# Will all java threads see shared resource updates after modification in synchronized method?

Tags: java, concurrency

Is it necessary to use specialized concurrent versions of Java's `Collections` data structures (e.g. CopyOnWriteArrayList vs ArrayList) if all access to a pair of data structures is always wrapped with the acquisition and release of a lock (in particular, using a static synchronized method for any modifications to the data structure). For example:

```
public static synchronized Item doIt() {
    // remove something from data structure 1
    // add the removed item to data structure 2
    // return removed item
}
```

I know the synchronized method will enforce only one thread at a time performing the updates, but by the time a thread has exited the method, are the other threads guaranteed to see the updated data structures, or do I still need specialized concurrent data structures for that guarantee?

**Edit:**

Here's a better example of what I'm trying to do:

```
private static final List<Item> A;
private static final HashMap<Integer,Item> B;

public static Item doSomething() {
    // some stuff ...
    Item item = doIt();
    // some other stuff ...
    return item;
}

private static synchronized Item doIt() {
    Item theItem = A.remove( A.size()-1 );
    B.put( theItem.getId(), theItem );
    return theItem;
}
```

Comment: You should not need such collections since you're manually performing the locking. But why to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Because you can't modify two collections atomically without locking.

Comment: @WilliamF.Jameson but these *concurrent versions* of the collections framework already have this locking handling and allow atomic operations on them. Again: why to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: But my question is whether or not the other threads will have their cache (their version of the data structure) updated after the synchronized block exits.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza OP has two collections. The two updates *as a whole* will not be atomic.

Comment: Are you always accessing them from `static`, `synchronized` methods in the *same class*? Synchronization will only help if you are always synchronizing on the same object. Do you know what object a `static` `synchronized` method synchronizes on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**, if the access is *always* wrapped in synchronized methods/blocks.

This is because, synchronized establishes a *happens-before* relation between synchronized methods/blocks (on the same object). Quoting from [Synchronized Methods in the Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html):

> Second, when a synchronized method exits, it automatically establishes
>   a happens-before relationship with any subsequent invocation of a
>   synchronized method for the same object. This **guarantees** that changes
>   to the state of the object are **visible to all threads**.

*However*, it is important that you really wrap all access in synchronized blocks. If you would, for example, return a reference to the list from a synchronized method like this

```
public synchronized List<Object> GetList() {
    return this.myList;
}
```

and use the list outside the synchronized method, you will not get that guarantee!

Comment: @RTF now I wonder why to have all of them as `static`. Looks like you have a design issue rather than a multi thread problem.

Answer (score 2):

Synchronization is about quite a bit more than just mutual exclusion. Namely, it is about the *visibility* of all actions which go on within the block (and precede it as well) to any other thread which subsequently acquires the same lock.

Therefore you don't need concurrent data structures when you use locking for all access to the structures.

Finally, just to make sure: you must use locking for *all* access, including all reads.